# Perf and kallsyms in a GKE Ephemeral container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, perf, google-container-os

I'd like to build an Ephemeral container where I can attach *perf*, *bpftrace*, or *gdb* to a running process. It would be helpful to get the kernel symbols; however, they are all "zeroed" in `/proc/kallsyms`, and there seems to be no way to get them from the underlying ContainerOS.

Is it just verboten? Am I beating my head against the proverbial brick wall??

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following [link](https://gist.github.com/moio/97c55fd742f407e294d370e4f4876f96) to create a privileged pod or deployment that is allowed in securityContext as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: proc-writer
  labels:
    app: proc-writer
spec:
  nodeName: "${NODE_NAME}"
  volumes:
  - name: host-proc
    hostPath:
      path: /proc
  containers:
  - name: alpine
    image: alpine:latest
    command: 
      - "sh"
      - "-c"
      - >
        while true; do
          sleep 3600;
        done
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /host-proc
          name: host-proc
```

Comment: Can you create a so-privileged ephemeral container that's attached to an unprivileged container in a pod?